# Socket UDP client memory leak

Tags: c, sockets, udp

I coded a UDP socket client-server in C. The client sent a query to the server each second for a long time (e.g.: 1 week).
My code ran fine, but I can see in the timeline that the ram increased considerably, at around 14 hours the memory increased to 150M approximately.

The increment is in the client side, the server is working fine.

I need to detect what causes this problem because the program will be running for long time.

What's wrong in my code?

This is my code in the client side:

```
int consultar_servidor(char *t1_str_)
{
    struct timeval t_ini, t_fin, tv;
    double secs;
    char cadena_enviada[67];
    char cadena_recibida[67];
    char tx_str[51]= "|0000000000000000|0000000000000000|0000000000000000";
    int validacion, i;

    long long int t4;
    char t4_str[20];

    char t2_str_rec[20];
    char t2_pps_str_rec[20];

    char t3_str_rec[20];

    int nBytes, numfd;


    if (t1_str_ != 0)
    {
        strcpy(cadena_enviada,t1_str_);
        strcat(cadena_enviada,tx_str);
    }
    else
    {  
        error("Error recepcion t1");
        return 1;
    }   
    if (cont_parametros == 0)
    {
        set_param();
    }

    if ( connect( clientSocket, ( struct sockaddr * ) &serverAddr, sizeof( serverAddr) ) < 0 ) 
        error( "Error connecting socket" ); 

    if ( sendto(clientSocket,cadena_enviada,sizeof(cadena_enviada),0,(struct sockaddr *)&serverAddr,addr_size) < 0)
    {
        close(clientSocket);
        error( "Error sentto function");
        cont_parametros = 0;
        return 1;
    }   

    /** Socket nonblock **/
    int flags = fcntl(clientSocket, F_GETFL, 0);
    fcntl(clientSocket, F_SETFL, flags | O_NONBLOCK);
    fd_set readfds;

    FD_ZERO(&readfds);
    FD_SET(clientSocket, &readfds);
    numfd = clientSocket + 1;   

    /** Set 700us to receive **/
    tv.tv_sec=0;
    tv.tv_usec=700000;  

    /** Server send me **/
    int recibo = select(numfd, &readfds,NULL,NULL,&tv);

    switch (recibo) 
    {
        case -1:
            /** Error reception **/
            error("Error reception");
            FD_CLR(clientSocket, &readfds);
            close(clientSocket);
            cont_parametros=0;
            return 1;
        case 0:
            /** Timeout and close socket **/
            error( "Error timeout" );
            FD_CLR(clientSocket, &readfds);
            close(clientSocket);
            cont_parametros = 0;
            return 1;
        default:
            /** If socket contain data **/
            if (FD_ISSET(clientSocket, &readfds)) 
            {
                /** catch t4 **/
                t4=ts();
                sprintf(t4_str, "%lld", t4);

                /** Receive server message**/
                nBytes = recvfrom(clientSocket,cadena_recibida,sizeof(cadena_recibida),0,NULL, NULL);
                /** If si a bad data **/
                if (nBytes < 0)
                {
                    error( "Error recept data" );
                    FD_CLR(clientSocket, &readfds);
                    close(clientSocket);
                    cont_parametros = 0;
                    return 1;               
                }

                /** Clean  set **/
                FD_CLR(clientSocket, &readfds);

                int i;

                /** trim t2**/
                for(i=17;i<33;i++)  t2_str_rec[i-17]=cadena_recibida[i];
                t2_str_rec[16]= '\0';

                /** trim t3**/
                for(i=34;i<51;i++)  t3_str_rec[i-34]=cadena_recibida[i];
                t3_str_rec[16]= '\0';

                printf("%s|%s|%s|%s\n",t1_str_, t2_str_rec, t3_str_rec, t4_str);
                return 0;
            }   
    }
}
```

---

And the function to set the params socket:

```
void set_param()
{
    /** Set client params  **/
    memset(&local_addr, 0, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
    local_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    local_addr.sin_port = htons(SRC_PORT);

    local_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(SRC_IP);

    /** Configure settings in address struct **/
    serverAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serverAddr.sin_port = htons(DST_PORT);
    serverAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(DST_IP);
    memset(serverAddr.sin_zero, '\0', sizeof serverAddr.sin_zero);  

    addr_size = sizeof serverAddr;

    clientSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    if ( clientSocket < 0 )
    {
        error( "Error socket no create" );
        exit(1);    
    }
    if (bind(clientSocket, (struct sockaddr *)&local_addr, sizeof(local_addr))< 0)
    {
        close(clientSocket);
        error( "Error  bind in socket" );
        exit(1);
    }   
    /** Socket create OK**/
    cont_parametros = 1;
}
```

---

The main part

```
    int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    long long int t1;           
    char t1_str[20];            
    while(1)
    {
        t1=ts();  
        sprintf(t1_str, "%lld", t1);  
        consultar_servidor(t1_str);
        sleep(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you allocate `char *t1_str_`? (Where and how do you call `int consultar_servidor(char *t1_str_)`?

Comment: The main part is added now to complete the code

Answer (score 2):

The main problem is that you call

```
close(clientSocket);
```

for all branches of the code except when you successfully read the data with `recvfrom` and return with code `0` from `consultar_servidor()`. As a result, the socket is never closed and there is a socket descriptor leak.

There may be other bugs in the code, make sure to test it under valgrind.

I suggest to restructure the code to avoid duplication and help to catch bugs such as these. For example, one option is to move the cleanup code to a separate function. Another option is to use the `goto` [cleanup pattern](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/c/MEM12-C.+Consider+using+a+goto+chain+when+leaving+a+function+on+error+when+using+and+releasing+resources), unless you're paranoid about not having `goto` in your code.

Comment: Not to mention `"|0000000000000000|0000000000000000|0000000000000000"` is 52 bytes, not 51, and a max long value is 19 chars, so the whole string can exceed 67 chars. There may be other issues as well...

Comment: I need to keep the socket open while no errors occurs, this is the reason to not use  close(clientSocket)  after recvfrom. I do it that  to avoid opening and closing the socket every each query and save processing time. Do You think some way to do this?

Comment: My mistake then, but that was not at all clear from the code you provided (as an English speaker, the meaning of the apparent global variable `cont_parametros` that you never show is hard to guess). If you're concerned about performance, why do you reconnect and unblock the socket every time then? Potentially there is something interesting going on here, but without a more clear question people will not be motivated to debug your code for you. Or, perhaps simpler, you can always close and reopen the socket.

Comment: cont_parametros is a global variable, it is like a flag to determine when a error occurred. Now I'm going to do the simpler way, to close and reopen the socket. After a couple of hours I will observe the behavior of the program and comment you again.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any actual memory allocations in the posted code, so if there is a direct memory leak, it must be caused by a problem somewhere else in the program.

As @kfx mentioned, another possibility is a socket leak; since each socket comes with buffers that use up a certain amount of RAM, that could show up as increased memory usage as well.

An easy way to test to see if your program is leaking sockets would be to add something like this to your program:

```
static int socketCount = 0;

int debug_socket(int domain, int type, int protocol)
{
   int ret = socket(domain, type, protocol);
   if (ret >= 0)
   {
      ++socketCount;
      printf("After socket() call succeeded, there are now %i sockets in use by this program\n", socketCount);
   }
   else perror("socket() failed!");

   return ret;
}

int debug_close(int sock)
{
   int ret = close(sock);
   if (ret == 0)
   {
      --socketCount;
      printf("After close() call succeeded, there now %i sockets in use by this program\n", socketCount);
   }
   else perror("close() failed!");

   return ret;
}
```

... then temporarily replace all the calls to socket() in your program with debug_socket(), and all the calls to close() in your program with debug_close().

Then run your program, and watch its stdout output.  If the numbers printed in the debug output are constantly increasing, your program is leaking sockets and you'll need to figure out why/how and fix it.  If not, then you have some other problem elsewhere.

Comment: thank you for your suggestion @jeremy-friesner. I change my code with your two functions and the variable socketCount everytime changue between 1 and 0.
I'm thinking maybe the problem in my operative system, my code it's running over a raspbian 8 in a raspberry pi3.